# Compare the elements of two arrays with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

This is my piece of code, I want to display the difference of every element of array1 to array2, When I am doing this way it is not giving the expected output.
Can anyone please tell how can I take the difference up to two decimal place, considering I have comma too in the data?

Expected output

```
arr3= ["$20.00", "$150.60", "-$0.50", "$168.20", "Can't Compare", "$0", "$0", "-$1000.00","-$300.00", "Can't compare", "Can't compare"]
```

```js
arr1 = ["$33.90", "$161.90", "$53.30", "$186.20", "Match up to $350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$6,000.00", "$6,650.00", "$13,300.00", "None"]
    arr2 = ["$13.90", "$11.30", "$53.80", "$18.00", "$350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$7,000.00", "$6,950.00", "Match up to $350 ", "Not available"]

    arr3 = [];
    function difference() {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
            const regex = /\d+/;
            let firstnum = parseInt(arr1[i].match(regex));
            let secondnum = parseInt(arr2[i].match(regex));

            let diff = firstnum - secondnum;
            if (isNaN(diff)) {
                    diff = `Can't Compare`;
                }
                else if (diff < 0) {
                    diff = Math.abs(diff)
                    diff= `-$${diff}`
                }
                else {
                    diff =  `$${diff}`
                }
            arr3.push(diff)
        }

        alert(arr3)
    }

    difference();
```

Comment: hi =D you should consider pruposed set of test to point what should be the result for specific input

Comment: Actually, what if  arr1 and arry2 both have the same item ```match up to $300```?

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple issues in the function. `parseInt` will convert any target into a whole number, so that was eliminating all your decimals. You can use `parseFloat`, `Number` or simply a `+`. Then, the regex was stripping out everything except numbers, so the decimal was getting removed there as well. Finally, once the difference was calculated, we needed to test if it was a fraction (using the modulus `diff % 1 !== 1`), and if so, make sure there were 2 decimal places (`diff.toFixed(2)`).  Actually I went back and made any non zero diff that way but left in the modulus in case you were interested.

The 'Cant compare' part was interesting because we were converting everything to numbers so a sentence like 'Match up to $300' was being turned into 300 and 'This is a sentence' was being turned into 0. To catch those, I added a second regex which basically looked for letters or spaces. If it found any, that item was marked as a `NaN`.

```js
arr1 = ["$33.90", "$161.90", "$53.30", "$186.20", "Match up to $350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$6,000.00", "$6,650.00", "$13,300.00", "None"]
arr2 = ["$13.90", "$11.30", "$53.80", "$18.00", "$350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$7,000.00", "$6,950.00", "Match up to $350 ", "Not available"]

arr3 = [];

function difference() {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {

    const regexAlpha = /[A-Za-z ]+/;
    let NaN = (arr1[i].match(regexAlpha) + arr2[i].match(regexAlpha)).length > 0;

    const regex = /[0-9.]+/;
    let firstnum = Number(arr1[i].match(regex));
    let secondnum = Number(arr2[i].match(regex));
    let diff
    if (NaN) {
      diff = `Can't Compare`;
    } else {
      diff = firstnum - secondnum;
      let sign = diff < 0 ? "-" : "";
      diff = Math.abs(diff)
      //if (diff % 1 !== 0) {
        if (diff !=0) diff = diff.toFixed(2);
      //}

      diff = sign + `$${diff}`

    }
    arr3.push(diff)
  }

  console.log(arr3)

}

difference();
```

Comment: Thanks but It's not working as expected

Comment: @user15895653 Sorry, I saw that after posting. It's fixed now and I will add some more explanation

Answer (score 1):

The main issues with your logic were because you parsed the values to integers, removing the decimal precision. The original regex was also flawed as it did the same thing.

One approach to this issue would be to use a more expansive regex which pulls out any value recognised as a price from either string, converts it to a floating point number and then performs the subtraction.

There's also a little extra code in the following example which ensures both strings provided price values and can be compared, even in cases where the value is wrapped in a string such as 'Match up to $350', and formats the output as a USD formatted string. Try this:

```js
let arr1 = ["$33.90", "$161.90", "$53.30", "$186.20", "Match up to $350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$6,000.00", "$6,650.00", "$13,300.00", "None"]
let arr2 = ["$13.90", "$11.30", "$53.80", "$18.00", "$350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$7,000.00", "$6,950.00", "Match up to $350 ", "Not available"]

let getPriceMatches = str => (str || '').match(/[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?/g)
let removeCommas = str => (str || '').replace(/\,/g, '');

function difference(a1, a2) {
  return a1.map((_, i) => {
    let price1Match = getPriceMatches(a1[i]);
    let price2Match = getPriceMatches(a2[i]);
    if (!price1Match || !price2Match)
      return 'Cannot compare';

    return (parseFloat(removeCommas(price1Match[0])) - parseFloat(removeCommas(price2Match[0]))).toLocaleString('en-US', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'USD',
    });
  });
}

let diff = difference(arr1, arr2);
console.log(diff);
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the regex to `/^\$\d+(?:.\d+)?/g` to detect currency string only. Remove `,` before text with the regex.

If the string not match with the regex, return `"Can't Compare"`.

Try to parse number string to float instead of int, then round the `diff` to 2 digits.

```js
const arr1 = ["$33.90", "$161.90", "$53.30", "$186.20", "Match up to $350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$6,000.00", "$6,650.00", "$13,300.00", "None"]
const arr2 = ["$13.90", "$11.30", "$53.80", "$18.00", "$350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$7,000.00", "$6,950.00", "Match up to $350 ", "Not available"]

const arr3 = [];

function difference() {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    const regex = /^\$\d+(?:.\d+)?/g;

    const firstStr = arr1[i].replace(/,/g, "").match(regex);
    const secondStr = arr2[i].replace(/,/g, "").match(regex);

    if (firstStr === null || secondStr === null) {
      arr3.push("Can't Compare");
      continue;
    }

    
    let firstnum = parseFloat(firstStr[0].replace("$", ""));
    let secondnum = parseFloat(secondStr[0].replace("$", ""));


    let diff = firstnum - secondnum;
    if (isNaN(diff)) {
      diff = `Can't Compare`;
    } else if (diff < 0) {
      diff = Math.abs(diff)
      diff = `-$${diff.toFixed(2)}`
    } else {
      diff = `$${diff.toFixed(2)}`
    }
    arr3.push(diff)
  }

  console.log(arr3)
}

difference();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if `$` is at the same index and get the normalized values and take the delta for the result with formatting.

```js
function difference(a, b) {
    const
        getValue = s => {
            const
                index = s.lastIndexOf('$'),
                value = +s.slice(index + 1).replace(/,/g, '');

            return { index, value };
        },
        result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        const
            aa = getValue(a[i]),
            bb = getValue(b[i]);

        if (aa.index !== -1 && aa.index === bb.index && isFinite(aa.value) && isFinite(bb.value)) {
            let delta = aa.value - bb.value;
            delta = delta ? delta.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }) : '$0';
            result.push(delta);
        } else {
            result.push("Can't Compare");
        }
    }
    return result;
}

const
    array1 = ["$33.90", "$161.90", "$53.30", "$186.20", "Match up to $350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$6,000.00", "$6,650.00", "$13,300.00", "None"],
    array2 = ["$13.90", "$11.30", "$53.80", "$18.00", "$350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$7,000.00", "$6,950.00", "Match up to $350 ", "Not available"],
    result = difference(array1, array2);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that considers a number invalid if has letters in it, and uses only numbers and decimals to determine the number.

```js
const arr1 = ["$33.90", "$161.90", "$53.30", "$186.20", "Match up to $350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$6,000.00", "$6,650.00", "$13,300.00", "None"];
const arr2 = ["$13.90", "$11.30", "$53.80", "$18.00", "$350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$7,000.00", "$6,950.00", "Match up to $350 ", "Not available"];
const VALID_REGEX = /[0-9]\.?/g;
const INVALID_REGEX = /[A-z]/g;

function getNumber(str) {
  const numMatches = str.match(VALID_REGEX);
  if (!numMatches || !numMatches.length) return NaN;
  const letterMatches = str.match(INVALID_REGEX);
  if (letterMatches && letterMatches.length > 0) return NaN;
  return parseFloat(numMatches.join(''), 10); // Need parseFloat rather than parseInt
}

function getDiffAt(arr1, arr2, i) {
    // if (arr1[i] === arr2[i]) return 0; // Could add this to match your expected results, but seems wrong
    const n1 = getNumber(arr1[i]);
    const n2 = getNumber(arr2[i]);
    // console.log(i, arr1[i], n1, arr2[i], n2);
    if (isNaN(n1) || isNaN(n2)) return "Can't compare";
    return n1 - n2;
}

function getDiffArray(arr1, arr2) {
    return arr1.map((str, i) => getDiffAt(arr1, arr2, i));
}

const diffArr = getDiffArray(arr1, arr2);
console.log(diffArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your logic correctly, but I assumed (by looking at your expected output) that if the array element doesn't have any digits or it "matches **up** to" certain value, it can't be compared.
Therefore, you could strip those "Matches up to ..." regexp matches in both arrays from any value because they aren't comparable anyways. I did this for both arrays using two map() functions (which is probably a bit redundant).
 Then you can just use regexp on both elements of the same index in arrays to detect digits (and dots because values with decimals are valid!) and if at least one result is empty it means it contains only characters, so you can safely return "Can't compare" otherwise you return the actual difference between values with adding .toFixed(2) if difference > 0 in order to add two decimals.

```js
let arr1 = ["$33.90", "$161.90", "$53.30", "$186.20", "Match up to $350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$6,000.00", "$6,650.00", "$13,300.00", "None"]
let arr2 = ["$13.90", "$11.30", "$53.80", "$18.00", "$350 ", "Match to $700 ", "$3,000.00", "$7,000.00", "$6,950.00", "Match up to $350 ", "Not available"]
let arr3 = [];

const difference = () => {

  arr1 = arr1.map((ele, index) => {
    if (ele.match(/up/i)) {
      return 'Can\'t compare';
    }
    return ele;
  })
  arr2 = arr2.map((ele, index) => {
    if (ele.match(/up/i)) {
      return 'Can\'t compare';
    }
    return ele;
  })
  arr3 = arr1.map((price, index) => {
    const diff = price.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')
    const diff2 = arr2[index].replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
    if (!diff.trim() || !diff2.trim()) return 'Can\'t compare';
    const absoluteDifference = Math.abs(diff - diff2);
    return `${diff < diff2 ? `-` : ``}$${absoluteDifference > 0 ? absoluteDifference.toFixed(2) : absoluteDifference}`;
  })
  console.log(arr3);
}
difference();
```